# Call Apple() method, set new object to a variable and return Banana() method instead

Tags: php, laravel, oop

Guys I'm trying to do that thing.
I have that object `$obj = Fruits::getFruit()->Apple();`. As you can see I'm calling `Apple()` method after `getFruit()` and I'm trying to keep the `Apple()` methods ouptut to $keep variable and I want to return `Banana()` method instead of `Apple()` but id doesn't work.

**Can I do something like this in php or it's unpossible?**

```
class Fruits
{
    public static $keep;
    
    public static function getFruit()
    {
        self::$keep = new self;
        var_dump(self::$keep);
        
        return self::Banana();
    }
    
    public function Apple()
    {
        return ['func' => 'Apple', 'output' => 'An apple'];
    }
    
    public function Banana()
    {
        return ['func' => 'Banana', 'output' => 'A Banana'];
    }
}


$obj = Fruits::getFruit()->Apple();
echo'<pre>';
var_dump($obj);
echo'</pre>';
```

Comment: like this `$obj = Fruits::getFruit();`?

Comment: `getFruit()` is creating an instance of your class and calling Banana statically, I think you need to re-think what `getFruit()` is doing. Because its not clear what its trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is what you are looking for? Because i did not understand clearly what is your purpose.

```
<?php
class Fruits
{
    

    public function getFruit():Fruits
    {
        
       $this->keep='Im getting fruits';

        return $this;
    }

    public  function Apple():Fruits
    {
        $this->keep.=' I have got and Apple';
        return $this;
        
    }

    public function Banana():Fruits
    {
        $this->keep.=' I ve got a Banana';
        return $this;
    }
}

$fruits= new Fruits;
$fruits->getFruit()->Apple()->Banana();
```

This class is not static and need to be instantiated.

Anyway here you are anther example of something 'like' a Laravel Facade.
In the example you can call any of defined methods statically, but will return a dinamic object again.

```
<?php
class FruitsDinamicObjet
{
    public $keep;
    public function getFruit()
    {

       $this->keep.=' Im getting fruits ';

        return $this;
    }

    public  function Apple()
    {
        $this->keep.=' I have got and Apple ';
        return $this;

    }

    public function Banana()
    {
        $this->keep.=' I ve got a Banana';
        return $this;
    }
}

Class Fruits{
   protected static FruitsDinamicObjet $myMagicObject;
    private static  $methods= [
        'Apple' => 'Apple',
        'Banana' => 'Banana',
        'getFruit' => 'getFruit'
    ];

  
   public static function Apple(){
       return (new FruitsDinamicObjet)->Apple();
   }
    public static function Banana(){
        return (new FruitsDinamicObjet)->Banana();
    }
    public static function getFruit(){
        return (new FruitsDinamicObjet)->getFruit();
    }
    public static function __callStatic(string $method, array $parameters)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('method', self::$methods)) {
            throw new Exception('The ' . $method . ' is not supported.');
        }

        return call_user_func_array(self::$methods[$method], $parameters);
    }
}
Fruits::Apple()->getFruit()->Banana()->keep;
```

Here you are some detailed information about [how facades works in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/facades#how-facades-work)

Comment: Thanks, It's not exactly what I wanted by It helped me.